# output/log variable value before exit in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I need to know if eclipse can output a value to log or console before I hit terminate on the process.

Lets say I have a method that does this:

```
 long cnt = 0;
 while(true)
      {
        cnt ++;
      }
```

I would hit run and it will increment it and then I ll hit terminate[in the eclipse run option] to terminate the program. Before it exits I want eclipse to output/log the value of cnt.

If thats not available atleast eclipse can log/output the value say every minute or few seconds.. so that at the end I would be off only by values within a mins range.

I am trying to benchmark something and I want to know how fast I can go on my hardware before I run my test. Hence I don't want any conditional statements etc in the program to slow it down.

Any pointers ?

Thanks

Comment: this does not sound like a meaningful benchmark of anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this - and Eclipse really does not have much to do with it - is to add a `ShutdownHook` ([link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29)) to the runtime of your code. The basic purpose of a shutdown hook is to provide a mechanism for your application to do some cleanup operations when the JVM is exiting.

However, you are fore warned that this is not a highly recommended way of doing things, but should only be employed for performing low risk operations which won't impact the overall sanctity of your application when it starts up again. this is because there's no guarantee as to how long the OS will allow the JVM process to exit.

in your case, i think you can go ahead and use it, since printing the value of a variable should not take too much time.

Comment: hey thanks .. I thought over it before but assumed that shutdown hooks wont be executed on 'terminate' .. will check if that works. Thnx

Comment: actually i don't think it'll work w/ Eclipse if you press that red-square button to force-termination. this will work when your application is terminated "normally" by Eclipse once the execution has completed.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't print any values when JVM is terminated.

To print value very so often you can add something like this:

```
long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
long cnt = 0;
while (true) {
  cnt++;
  if((System.currentTimeMillis()-l) > 2000L) {
    l = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.err.println(cnt);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse does not invoke shutdownHooks on click of big red terminate button:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=38016

Design code to not require the shutdown hook, if it's a concern.